# Bias be larger than variance in ERM

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation

Given a convex set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and some $\theta\in S$, consider the observation $y=\theta+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon\sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$, the ERM estimator is
$$\hat{\theta}=\arg \min_{x\in S}\|x-y\|_2.$$
Consider the usual bias-variance decomposition
$$\mathbb{E}\|\hat\theta-\theta\|^2=\|\mathbb{E}\hat\theta-\theta\|^2+var(\hat\theta)=bias^2+variance.$$
Does there exists some $S$ and $\theta$, such that the bias term is much larger than the variance term?

For example, for 1D linear regression on $x_1,...,x_n\in\mathbb{R}$, the $S$ here is $S=\{(y_1,...,y_n):y_i=kx_i+b, k,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so the estimator is unbiased.

Comment: Do you have some Context to include ? [[ Eg : Where you got this Question from ? Why you want to know the Answer ? What work you did till now ? Where you got stuck ? ]] The Question seems quite interesting !! When you include some Context , it may well get reopened & answered !!